# Mount and unmount a drive for backup

Tags: hard-drive, mount, windows-11, unmount

In windows I want to create backups (using robocopy) on my internal hard drive.  However, I want to keep the hard drive mounted only during backups and unmount it rest of the time.  The reason is attacks like ransomeware destroy data on all mounted drives.  I want to use a script to mount the drive before backup and then unmount it right after the backup.  I can use
mountvol g: /p
to unmount the drive, but when I use
mountvol g: \?.........
to mount the drive for backup, it does not work.  The reason is when mountvol /p is used it makes the volume unmountable.
What could I do to ensure that when the volume is unmounted, it does not become unmountable?